# Center jQuery info alert

Tags: jquery-ui, center

How can I center the text and icon in the standard jQuery info alert?

http://jsfiddle.net/3kHWa/

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked at the snippet and have it centered with this snippet http://jsfiddle.net/3kHWa/2/

```
<div class="ui-widget">
 <div class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all" style="padding: 0pt 0.7em;"> 
  <div style="width:auto;margin:0 auto;display:table;">
   <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="float: left; margin-right: 0.3em;"></span>
    any size text</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have in addition a problem with this. How can I achieve this also with a list. So that the icon is placed at the left side from the first `<li>`. http://jsfiddle.net/3kHWa/4/

Comment: change the <ul> to <ul style="float:left;">

Comment: Thanks but I want have the numbers in one column. Sorry for my English. ;-)

Comment: @shub you can simply add a `margin-left` to the `li`s, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/william/3kHWa/9/.